# add recursive number with condition in dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, recursion

i have problem with add some records table with particular condition.
for example, i have this kind of table

```
  id word count 
1  1  aa    2 
2  2  bb    3
```

then, i want to change and add some number in id column with similar data for other column like this

```
  id  word count 
1 100  aa    2 
2 101  aa    2 
3 102  aa    2 
4 103  aa    2 
5 200  bb    3 
6 201  bb    3 
7 202  bb    3
8 203  bb    3
```

the id column need to add with 2 digits in behind and then add recursive number after without changing other column data. Supposed that i have thousand records, i wonder how to make this happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear from the description.  Based on the expected output, an option is to create a `list` column by looping over the 'id', get the `seq`uence after multiplying by '4' and then `unnest` the `list` column

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(id = map(id*100, seq, length.out = 4)) %>% 
    unnest(c(id))
# A tibble: 8 x 3
#     id word  count
#  <dbl> <chr> <int>
#1   100 aa        2
#2   101 aa        2
#3   102 aa        2
#4   103 aa        2
#5   200 bb        3
#6   201 bb        3
#7   202 bb        3
#8   203 bb        3
```

---

Or another option is to replicate the rows (`uncount`), grouped by 'word', modify the 'id'

```
df1 %>%
    uncount(4) %>% 
    group_by(word) %>% 
    mutate(id = seq(100 * first(id), length.out = n()))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:2, word = c("aa", "bb"), count = 2:3), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2"))
```

Comment: I don't have experience with `fsttable`, sorry

Comment: Thank you akrun.. it works perfectly..
really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Try the following base R function.
It loops (`lapply`) over column `'id'` creating a vector like the one in the question and then putting the other columns in order in a data.frame, then combines (`rbind`) all these df's into the return value.

```
fun <- function(x, n = 3){
  cols <- grep('id', names(x), invert = TRUE)
  out <- lapply(x[['id']], function(i){
    y <- sprintf(paste0(i, "%02d"), c(0L, seq.int(n)))
    y <- data.frame(id = y)
    for(j in cols) y[[j]] <- x[i, j]
    y
  })
  out <- do.call(rbind, out)
  row.names(out) <- NULL
  out
}

fun(df1)
#   id V2 V3
#1 100 aa  2
#2 101 aa  2
#3 102 aa  2
#4 103 aa  2
#5 200 bb  3
#6 201 bb  3
#7 202 bb  3
#8 203 bb  3
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
  id word count 
1  1  aa    2 
2  2  bb    3 
", header = TRUE)
```